# What is happening in this code?

Tags: c#, object, methods

I am looking at somebodies code and I was wondering if someone could explain to me what I am looking at here.

```
    public static KillerInspectorScene Instance
    {
        get 
        {
            if (instance == null) {
                throw new InvalidProgramException();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
```

I haven't seen a method like this before, can someone tell me what I'm looking at? I think I understand the body of the method. Can anyone tell me what this is exactly so I can look it up further on google? I have something similar below I cant figure out either.

```
    public KillerInspectorScene.States GetKillerResultState(Game.KillerActions action)
    {
        if (action == Game.KillerActions.Disguise) {
            return KillerInspectorScene.States.Disguise;
        }
        else if (action == Game.KillerActions.Kill) {
            return KillerInspectorScene.States.Kill;
        }
        else if (action == Game.KillerActions.Shift) {
            return KillerInspectorScene.States.Shift;
        }
        return KillerInspectorScene.States.Null;
    }
```

Help would be GREATLY appreciated. I can't look up the name of something I don't know the name to. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean "a method like this"? It's hard to tell what exactly about the code you don't understand. It's a static read-only property. The second one is a non-static method. I'm not sure what you mean by "similar"..

Comment: Why can't you ask the owner of the code?

Comment: Ah, yeah I really had no idea what I was looking at. I thought properties needed to be a variable int, double, float etc. Thanks for the response I comprehend this a lot more now!

Comment: @user42537 Your question is a bit unclear. Are you able to improve your answer with a bit more detail and perhaps phrase limit it to a single question? Also, are you new to C# or are you wanting to understanding coding patterns better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The first method you looking at is a validation: 
   If somehow the KillerInspectorScene instance is nullified it means that an other method in the program made an invalid operation regarding the logic of the game and so it will throw an error.
2. The second method you looking at is a choice according to an action being made, it seems that there are 3 options for a killer to react and that method is "digesting" those options.

   It receives the action of the killer and returns the scene state according to that action.

I suggest that you check who is calling the methods and in which occasions exactly to learn more of your code.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have a public static getter on a static property called Instance. The instance field is initialized somewhere else. If it is not initialized the getter throws an exception. The Instance property is globally accessible in your program.

The second is a method and part of a instance of your class. Given an action it returns some sort of KillerInspectorScene state.

Answer (score -2):

You are looking at a [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: ..not really, since accessing `Instance` throws a nullref. Its not "classic" singleton anyway..

Comment: if it were a singleton pattern, wouldn't the method be creating a new instance rather than throwing an exception?

Comment: Links can be helpful as supplemental information, but [link-only answers are strongly discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/228805). Please include a summary of the linked information that's relevant to the question, and explain how it resolves the issue.

Comment: +1. not exactly sure why it is "not a singleton pattern" - looks like part of one to me. Likely code that initialize `instance` is somewhere else and the `Instance` property just makes sure initialization is completed. (Don't see why it would deserve -1 anyway).

Comment: @mezoid - why would it must be creating new instance? This piece of code not necessary knows exact type of the `instance` so it may not be able to new one up...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov At the very least it is a poorly implemented singleton pattern. It is very hard to give a complete answer without seeing where the instance is initialized and if it is publicly accessible. Also, the code does know what the exact type is...it is a KillerInspectorScene.

Comment: @mezoid - How do you know that `KillerInspectorScene` is `sealed`?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I think I may be misunderstanding your question. I don't know if `KillerInspectorScene` is sealed or not without seeing the class definition.

Comment: @mezoid "the code does know what the exact type is." is true *only* if return type is `sealed`, otherwise any derived type will be acceptable. Unrelated comment: `new`-ing up instance in a method is also considered "code smell" by some - so I personally would not welcome code that has `new` in that `Instance` call (but it can be considered personal preference... like general dislike for Singleton/Service locator patterns).